# Android - Logout from twitter with twitter4j

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

`twitter4j` works fine for Login and share .
But I am unable to logout from it.
For logout i am clearing preference, but each time it 
display last user as logged in. Below is my code for logout,

```
SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences =getSharedPreferences( "Twitter-Credentials",MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE); 
Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();
e.remove(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN);
e.remove(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET);
e.remove(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN); 
e.commit();
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I solved issue just changing Call back url from        oauth://t4jsample     to...    public static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?force_login=true";

Comment: Put this piece of code in the answer section and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved issue just changing Call back url from oauth://t4jsample to... public static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?force_login=true";

Comment: Thanks Its useful for me.